# PeriodicTask with Django + Celery

Tags: python, django, task, celery

I am trying to do a Periodic task in my project but I can't make it work. In my dev I execute celery like this:

```
python manage.py celery worker -l info
```

But when I try:

```
celery -B -l info
```

or

```
python manage.py celery -B -l info
```

I get a `Connection refused error`.
I have also installed [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) to monitoring if the task is executed. I have other tasks executen from code, but now I'd like to do a periodical task.

My tasks (that actually works) inherits from `celery.task.Task` and the Task I want to be periodical from `celery.task.PeriodicTask`, something like this:

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask

TaskToBePeriodical(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = crontab()  # This should make it execute every minute, just for test
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # Do something awesome...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your command to start celery isn't quite correct.
Depending on what you are trying to schedule, you may want to try setting it up as as celery.beat.

*It might be worth noting that this method does not use django-celery, as the Celery docs mentions that, "THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER REQUIRED"*

See here to learn more about celery.beat:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.beat.html

**Celery start command**

```
celery -A proj.celery_app worker -l info -B
```

**Project Directories**

```
+-- proj
|   +-- celery_app.py
|   +-- settings.py
|   +-- urls.py
|   +-- ...
+-- app
|   +-- models.py
|   +-- tasks.py
|   +-- urls.py
|   +-- views.py
|   +-- ...
```

**celery_app.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'name_of_task': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_task',
        'schedule': crontab()
    }
}
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def periodic_task():
    # Do your awesome thing
    return
```

Comment: I have added a `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` dic in my `celery.py` (in your example `celery_app.py`). But when I run `celery worker....` I get `No module named celery` I have to do it with `python manage.py ...`, I executed `python manage.py celery beat` and it worked now it is (suposed) running. Finally I use class based tasks, like `MyTask(PeriodicTack)` from `from celery.task import PeriodicTask`

Comment: Well thanks!! You really helped me with that command line, I ran `python manage.py celery worker -l info -B` and now it is working perfectly, I still don't know how I need to use `python manage.py ...` if you have some idea about, i'll be glad you explain me. Now I am following [this](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) to execute it every 2 weeks, de you know how?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. If you are still interested. I remember vaguely getting an issue saying: `No module name celery` when I ran the `celery worker ....` command. This is commonly due to the fact that the official docs and many other guides have you name the same file I named here `celery_app.py` to `celery.py` which causes python imports to be confused. It isn't sure what you mean want to import the actual celery library or `celery.py`.

Comment: As for your question about `python manage.py ...` I, personally, wasn't aware that you could run the celery server using `python manage.py celery` command. I have only ever used `python manage.py ...` to run django specific commands. But it makes sense that this would work and be useful as it would import your project settings automatically. I actually ended writing a script to handle importing app settings for my app deployment.